# SQL fetching using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, fetch, cursors

Is there a possibility in SQL Server (and SQL generally) to define a cursor, then use it to fetch a row and assign it to variables, when I have less variables than columns? If so, how to decide which columns are assigned to particular variables?

Comment: please consider adding sample  data and the expected result in formatted text.
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: You have to assign variable to all columns returned by a cursor.  But, in general, you should be trying to avoid cursors.  There is often a set-based solution that is shorter and faster.

Comment: Well, I need to use this kind of logic, because I need first to check only few values. But I do not know if that's possible. Therefore, I didn't attempt to write such query, because I don't know if it's possible (how one can do something, when it's impossible?)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you. I know about low-efficiency of cursors, but my procedure is purely "row-based". Therefore, I can't avoid it. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn There is rarely an operation using a cursor that can not be written as a set based operation.

Comment: @SqlZim Well, I need to check for `NULL` in every cell of a row, if a cell is `NULL` then I have to assign a value based on previous row. I think it can not get anymore "row-based" :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn There are several ways to handle that without a cursor.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn . . . You should ask another question with sample data and desired results.  You can probably do that without a cursor.  The one situation where you can't use a cursor is when you need to run a stored procedure on each row.